# Setup Core Data relationship for ordering app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, entity-relationship

I have a cloud app that relies pureply on SQL on the backend servers. I now wish to create another app that instead uses core data to save the data in the ipad first, and whenever the user has internet access to automatically map my core data to the server.

I'm having a problem in porting over my database tables onto my core data entities.

1. I have a `products` table which will store product's that has properties such as *`name`, `price`, `product id`*
2. I have an `orderLines` table whicb will store individual items from a particular `order` with the following properties, `product`, `orderline_quantityOrdered`, `orderLine_totalPriceAtCheckOut`, `OrderId`. The order id is used to track which order the orderline is associated to.
3. Then we have the `orders` table which stores just information about the purchase like so `customer_id`, `OrderId` - used by the `orderlines` table to make the relationship, `datePurchased`, `totalOrderAmount`.

Now before Implementing this to coreData I understand that I dont need to create primary key id's because Core Data already has its own way of identifying rows with its own id attribute that it implements for each entity I create.

But how would I form the relationship from the `order` to `orderlines` table with `OrderId`. It will have a `one to many relationship` and that is how I connect the two.

```
//Example of orders table in the backend database
OrderId = 1, purchasedate, customer, orderTotalAmount
OrderId = 3, purchasedate, customer, orderTotalAmount
OrderId = 5, purchasedate, customer, orderTotalAmount

//Example of orderlines table in the backend databaset
oL_Id = 1, OrderId = 1, productNameAtTimeOfPurchase, productPriceATOP, quantity, subTotal
oL_Id = 2, OrderId = 1, productNameAtTimeOfPurhchase, productPriceATOP, quantity, subTotal
oL_Id = 3, OrderId = 1, productNameAtTimeOfPurchase, productPriceATOP, quantity, subTotal
oL_Id = 4, OrderId = 3, productNameAtTimeOfPurchase, productPriceATOP, quantity, subTotal
oL_Id = 7, OrderId = 3, productNameAtTimeOfPurchase, productPriceATOP, quantity, subTotal
oL_Id = 8, OrderId = 3, productNameAtTimeOfPurchase, productPriceATOP, quantity, subTotal
oL_Id = 10, OrderId = 5, productNameAtTimeOfPurchase, productPriceATOP, quantity, subTotal
```

I understand that CoreData is not ORM, thats fine, but if someone can guide me in setting up this Core data entity then that would be great. 
I'm not a beginner, I have handled Core Data before in other projects, I now need to implement a relationship in the entity editory in interface builder. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you would create an attribute for every attribute stored on the server. Even if Core Data won't be using it as a primary or foreign key you are still going to want to keep those for your syncing.

Second, you define the relationship in Core Data, bi-directional, as a one-to-many in the model editor.  Then in code you create an order object, create your orderLine (singular entity names are recommended/standard) and then put your orderLine instances into a set and pass that set to the order object.

Which part of that is unfamiliar to you and I will update my answer with more detail.